# Prevent the command line window from closing when an R script encounters an error

Tags: r, cmd

I have an R script which runs on Windows 10. It works on my computer, but not my colleague's computer. I also cannot access my colleague's computer, though I can see the screen (for WFH reasons). For diagnostic purposes, I want to make it so that the command line window does not close when R encounters an error or the script otherwise completes/stops running. How do I do this?

Follow-up: This was using Rscript.exe to run the script. Running it through RGui was what I did eventually - I briefly forgot RGui existed.

Regarding the original question, going into the command line first and running the script from there also worked. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. How are you running R (RStudio, RGui,  ...)? What kind of errors are you encountering (seg fault, R error message, ...)? Why are you trying to access your colleague's computer and what are you trying to achieve? A R error message should not close/crash your R session, but have you debugged your script and identified what line(s) are causing problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could previously open the command line and call your script from there (instead of executing it by double click).

Or call the script from a batch (.BAT) file with `PAUSE` as the last line.